# How to add a JSON body and Certificate

Tags: java, rest

I have tried for hours to add a Json body and a certificate to my request. Now I am frustrated and confused.
Here is a little code that I tidy up:

```java
try {
    // TODO: Add Json object in Body "myJSON"
    // TODO: Add Certificate "abc.p12" and password "123456".
    String request = WCFGlobalVariables.getApiUrl();
    URL url = new URL(request);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(WCFGlobalVariables.getProxyName(), WCFGlobalVariables.getProxyPort())));
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {

    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

I hope, you are willing to help me:

What Have I still do do to add a "P12"-Certificate and password, and an JSON as request body?

Thank for help!